# define addition as an instance of Num in haskell

Tags: haskell

I wish to define addition between two chars as concatination but im unsure of how to properly do so.

my attempt:

```
instance Num Char where
 (+) (a) (b) = [a] ++ [b]
```

but the error i get is that the  return type is not the expected one.

My expected output is as stated a list of Char which is formed by concatinating the two chars.

Comment: `(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`; you want something with type `Char -> Char -> [Char]`.

Comment: Even if you *did* come up with a definition of `+` that fit the signature, you can't define a `Num` instance without also defining `(*)`, `abs`, `signum`, `fromInteger`, and either `negate` or `(-)`. And if you *do* define them, they still need to obey various laws like `a + b == b + a` and `x + fromInteger 0 == x`. The kind of operator overloading provided by type classes is not the free-for-all, any-definition-goes kind provided by other languages.

Comment: @chepner The built-in `Natural` type doesn't have a reasonable definition of `negate` or `(-)`, and it breaks a lot of the "laws" (which aren't actually defined in the report).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than overload `(+)` with non-numeric semantics, define your own character "addition" operator.

```
import Data.Function

-- The ^ is meant to suggest lifting values into a list.
(^+) :: a -> a -> [a]
x ^+ y = (++) `on` pure
-- Or more simply,
-- x ^+ y = [x, y]
```

Then `'a' ^+ 'b' == "ab"`. `(^+)` will work for creating a two-element list of *any* type, not just `Char`.

```
> 'a' ^+ 'b'
"ab"
> 3 ^+ 4
[3,4]
> [1,2] ^+ [4,5]
[[1,2],[4,5]]
```

Comment: Bringing out the big cannons, eh? `on`, `pure`... you just barely missed generalizing `(++)` to `(<>)` to make it as inscrutable as possible. We have lost touch with how simple Haskell can be, it seems. `a ^+ b = [a, b]` (Upvoted anyway.)

Comment: Sorry, I performed what I thought was an edit suggestion but ended up actually editing the answer; my SO is a bit rusty.  I agree with the main idea of the answer, but proposed a more reasonable implementation of `^+`.  Feel free to edit back if you feel like the original implementation is more reasonable.

Comment: @JustinL. You have enough reputation that your edits don't need peer review: you're expected to know well enough how things work and not make wantonly unreasonable edits. Case in point: this edit was totally reasonable.

Comment: I'd prefer an addition to the answer rather than omitting the `on` solution altogether.

Answer (score 5):

This is impossible. The `(+)` function in `Num` has type `a -> a -> a`, so the return type must be the same as the parameter type. You cannot add two Char and receive a String as a result. More generally, you should not implement Num for things other than arithmetic on numbers.

Comment: I see, but if i took two strings as input and concatinated them, in other words a typesignature [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char], it would then be possible to define (+) on [Char] ?

Comment: The compiler would not complain, but any humans reading your program would.

Comment: The [docs for `Num`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.12/base-4.12.0.0/Prelude.html#t:Num) specify a few laws that instances should satisfy, and concatenating strings wouldn't fit them. For example, string concatenation wouldn't satisfy addition commutativity. The compiler will not object, but such instance will have weird behavior, unobvious to other people, and thus will lead to subtle bugs.

Comment: Also, it occurs to me now, the compiler *would* complain. You must define an instance for `[a]` in general, and cannot specialize to only `[Char]`. You could define addition for lists to be concatenation, but of course this would be widely reviled.